# How to restore mysql database backup from terminal?

Tags: mysql, backup

I make daily backups by running the following cronjob:

```sh
mysqldump --user root --password=xxxx databasename > /home/ec2-user/backup/databasebackup_$today
```

How would I go about to simply restore from a backup, completely overwriting whatever there might be?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with...

```
mysql --user=root --password=xxxx --database=databasename < /home/ec2-user/backup/databasebackup_$today
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
mysql -u root -p databasename < /home/ec2-user/backup/databasebackup_$today
```

You will be prompt to enter password. Supposing you are not planning to cron restore procedure.